# Why mapped items states are affecting on each other in React?

Tags: reactjs

I mapped an array of products, each of them have, I am managing state with redux, each mapped item has quantity if I increase quantity, price should also increase, so when I am changing quantity of one item second array price also changes based on previous item quantity, so why are different items affecting on each other? here is the code:

```
const handleProductQuantity = (event) => {
    dispatch(setProductQuantity(event.target.value));
}

 <div className='cart'>
        <div className='products-in-cart-wrapper'>
        { productsInCart ? (
             productsInCart.map(productInCart => (
                    <div className='product-in-cart'>
                        <div className="product-in-cart-name">
                            <div className="label label-title">
                              Title:
                            </div>
                            <div className="value value-title">
                                {productInCart.title}
                             </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="product-in-cart-price">
                             <div className="label label-price">
                                Price:
                             </div>
                             <div className="value value-price">
                                {productQuantity * productInCart.price}
                             </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="product-in-cart-price">
                             <div className="label label-price">
                                Quantity:
                             </div>
                             <div className="value value-quantity">
                                <input onChange={handleProductQuantity} type="number" placeholder='1'/>
                             </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="button-cont">
                            <button className="buy-button" onClick={test}>
                                Buy now
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            ))
        ) : (
            <div> Loading... </div>
        )
        }
        <div className="total-price-button-cont">
            <button>Buy all for: 100$</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: How is your `setProductQuantity` implemented? I don't see how it can know which product is being modified.

Comment: You need to pass an unique id to identify the product which you're going to update. Otherwise it won't be updating proper one.

Answer (score 0):

You should always use a key prop on items inside array. if you have an id by example, this would look like that :

```
<div className="product-in-cart" key={productInCart.id}>...</div>
```

React uses key to properly identify items inside the array. You problem might be different tho but you should always uses key

edit: `productQuantity` should be `productInCart.productQuantity` ;)

Comment: is it working as expected now ? :)

Comment: oh my god, it is still doing same, I don't know why

Comment: `productQuantity` should be `productInCart.productQuantity` ;)

Comment: oh I got it, so I will create it separately and they will not affect on each other

Comment: you quantity is not already stored by product in the cart ?

Comment: productQuantity is coming form redux, it is state, managed by redux, so every time I change quantity in number input, productQuantity is changed according to that

Comment: my question is : do you have a single quantiy variable for all the product in cart ?